# Create_Association does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails

it's been quite some time since i last wrote Rails and i've forgotten some stuff i guess :P I'm having a simple has_many through but i can't get create_association to work for some reason. The models are :

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :city_buildings
    has_many :buildings, :through => :city_buildings

class CityBuilding < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :city
    belongs_to :building
end
```

I write something like :

```
c = City.first
c.create_building
```

and i get :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create_building' for #<City:0x007f9a8f9494f0>
```

Why do i get that ? Any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
c = City.first
c.buildings.create :attribute => 'value'
```

[Methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) which the `has_many` declaration adds to your models.

Comment: i know about that but it's not what i want. i don't see why create_building does not work and i actually want to understand what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Because `create_association(attributes = {})` method will be added to your model only by `belongs_to` and `has_one` declarations. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to . So if you want to use this method you should create join model instance first `c.city_buildings.build.create_building(...)` or `c.city_buildings.create.create_building(...)` but it's so freaking long and not working.

Comment: hmm i see, so since i want to change a value that is actually on the city_buildings table, i would have to do it using the join model instance method, right ?

Comment: Well you want `create_building` so I'd said you actually want to **add** record to city_buildings table. And you can do that with line I've given you in the answer. *collection.create(attributes = {}) — 
Returns a new object of the collection type that has been instantiated with attributes, linked to this object through a foreign key, and that has already been saved (if it passed the validation).* according to api.